# Just installed 14.04. Can't find drivers for Brother MFC-J410W printer.

Tags: printing

I'm new to Ubuntu and just installed 14.04 on a Dell Dimension 8400.  When trying to get my printer loaded, my Brother MFC-J410W wasn't listed.

I think I found a driver but unsure how to do it from the terminal.  From what I gather I would need to be sudo su super user?

I know this is not a new question but I didn't see any posts for my particular printer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is one:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1961148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Linux driver available for this printer from [this page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj410w_us). Select Linux, and select `Linux (deb)`. On the next page, there is a "Driver install tool" listed. Click that (it is the most recent entry) and press "Agree to the Eula and download".

Now open a terminal and navigate to your Downloads directory. Enter `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz`. This will create a file `linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1`.

Now enter `sudo su` and enter your password. You now have superuser rights, so be careful (you can tell because the prompt character has changed from `$` to `#`). Still in the download directory, run:
`bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1` . This will start the driver installation.

After installation is complete, don't forget to enter `exit` to get out of the superuser shell.
Disclaimer: I have not tried this particular installation myself, but it is very similar to other installation procedures.